# Asset Pipeline Rails 3.2 not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

How to make Apache+Passenger and Rails Asset Pipeline work together nice?

When I deploy my locally working project, I get a 500 error

```
In ActionView::Template::Error occurred in pages#start: jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min isn't precompiled
```

If I grep `my_project/current/assets_manifest.yml` for `jquery-ui-1.8`, it gives me

```
 jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js: jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.minc50ea0bef9c2fae04ab3b50ead60fc1f.js
```

and this file also exists in `my_project/shared/assets` (along with jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min-c50ea0bef9c2fae04ab3b50ead60fc1f.js.gz, jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js.gz).

When I open 
`http://mytestserver/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min-c50ea0bef9c2fae04ab3b50ead60fc1f.js`
in browser it gives me the correct js file.

The 500 error is raised from

```
app/views/layouts/application.haml:25
```

line 24-26 of that file are:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min"
= csrf_meta_tag
```

So what could have gone wrong? Why is it not working?

Comment: Is it all right if you try to purge your the contents of your `assets` folder and run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` again?

Comment: I did `my_project/current/public/assets$ rm * -r` and 
`my_project/current$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and it's still the same..

Answer (score 0):

If the file isn't being loaded by `application.js` then you need to add a line to `application.rb` so the app knows about it:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js']
```

Comment: In the application.rb there is a line `config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )`.. shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: I've never tried passing wildcards to `config.assets.precompile` but a quick search suggests that other people doing this have had mixed results. Might be worth passing the actual filenames just to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I deactived the line.. Now in rails console in production I get `1.8.7 :003 > config.assets.precompile
"/(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/, "gmaps4rails.css", "jquery.fileupload-ui", "jquery.tagsinput", "jquery.Jcrop.min", "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min", "gmaps4rails.css", "jquery.fileupload-ui", "jquery.tagsinput", "jquery.Jcrop.min"`but I still get `1.8.7 :004 > helper.javascript_include_tag  "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min"
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError: jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min isn't precompiled`

Comment: The assets are located in /webapps/shoppl/current/public/assets and /webapps/shoppl/shared/assets (should be same via symbolic link I guess)

Comment: by the way, why should/shouldn't I pack the jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js to application.hs? Do I need this jquery-gem-thing?

Answer (score 0):

`shared/assets` is not a place that the asset pipeline typically looks for files.

Typically the asset pipeline looks in `app/assets`, it may look in `lib/assets` and I'm pretty sure it looks in `vendor/assets` also. But it's possible that the `vendor/assets` is not included by default, which I talk about below.

Per Rails convention I suggest you put that dependency in `vendor/assets/javascripts`

If you want to add search directories to the asset pipeline it's just a simple modification to `config.application.rb`

in the `YourProject::Application` declaration, add:

`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor/assets/javascripts")`

Or whatever other path you want.

Comment: On my development machine they are in my_project/app/assets.. I was talking about the server - therefore also the current and shared folders which are introduced by capistrano on production

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it.. I think this were the steps:

- renaming the rake-namespace of capistrano deployment (possible duplication of namespace and var damage) which was also doing the precompilation
- add each js file that I include via `javascript_include_tag` to config.assets.precompile for production environment like @Simon suggested
- in config.assets.precompile they seem to be mentioned without .js-extension, whereas in the `javascript_include_tag` directives they should be included with .js-extension